# how to send the output from drools to java

Tags: java, drools

Below is the drools i'm using based on conditions

```
import com.sample.TestExample;
import com.sample.TestExample.Message;

rule "Hello World"
when
    m : Message( product == Message.tv, myMessage : message )
then
    System.out.println(Message.tv);
    System.out.println("Product Spec is:: Service.TV_SAT"); // This output i want send back to java       
end

rule "GoodBye"
when
    n  : Message( product == Message.smart, myMessage : message )
then
    System.out.println(Message.smart);
    System.out.println("Product Spec is:: Service.SMARTOFFICE");  // This output i want send back to java   
end

rule "Else condition"
when
    e  : Message(product != TestExample.productClass)
then
    System.out.println(TestExample.productClass);
    System.out.println("in drools else condition"); // This output i want send back to java   
end
```

i tried using set and get methods, but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Comment: i tried like using set function---->>

 m.setProductSpec("Service.TV_SAT");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi My code is working after making the below changes in java code

public static class Message {

```
    private String message;

    public static String product;
    public static String tv="TV_SAT";
    public static String smart="SMART_OFFICE";

    public static String productSpec;

    public static int status;

    public String getProduct(){
        return Message.product;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product){
        Message.product=product;
    }

    public void setProductSpec(String product){

        Message.productSpec=product;
    }

    public String getProductSpec(){

        return
                Message.productSpec;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "send back to Java".

What you need to do depends on where you want this "output" to be stored. If you have a fields `messageText` in `Message`, then you can

```
 m.setMessageText( "your message" );
```

If this doesn't work, you may not have declared this setter, or you may have made some other mistake. (We need to see the declaration of the setter to be able to tell you more.)

You could use a global `List<String>` and add message texts to this collection object. See the doc how to use globals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-)

"send back to Java" means the output written by println() method should sent back to java variable which holds the current output.

With the help of set() method, it is displaying the output but i need to store that value

Comment: Please share the document link

Comment: Which "variable [...] holds the current output"? A setter usually stores, so call one that behaves like a setter. -- The "doc" is the drools_documentation that comes with the distribution. You have it on your system.

Comment: i'm using the current code in java, please check and validate
public void setProductSpec(String product){
         System.out.println("inside set product spec");
         Message.product=product;
        }
        
        public String getProductSpec(){
         System.out.println("inside get product spec");
         return
           Message.productSpec;

Answer (score 0):

Final drl file is the below:

```
package com.sample

import com.sample.TestExample;
import com.sample.TestExample.Message;

global java.util.List statuses;

rule "Hello World"
    when
        m : Message( product == Message.tv, myMessage : message )
    then
        System.out.println("Product Class::"+Message.tv);
        m.setProductSpec("Service.TV_SAT");
end

rule "GoodBye"
    when
        n  : Message( product == Message.smart, myMessage : message )
    then
        System.out.println("Product Class::"+Message.smart);
        n.setProductSpec("Service.SmartOffice");
end

rule "Else condition"
    when
        e  : Message(product != TestExample.productClass)
    then
        System.out.println(TestExample.productClass);
        System.out.println("in drools else condition");
end
```